# games crashing in windows 10 after upgrading to rtx 3080

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, crash, gaming

I started having issues with my ITX build after upgrading the GPU from a reference evga gtx 1070 to a EVGA xc3 ultimate rtx 3080 where loading up any game would either crash to desktop or hard crash and reboot the PC (without any BSOD error msg).

specs as followed:

```
amd 5800x3d
asus rog strix x570-i mobo
32gb (2x16) g.skill ripjaws v
sesasonic focus spx-750 evga gtx 1070 (reference) --> evga xc3 ult 3080 
windows 10 v20H2
```

no other changes to anything aside from upgrading the GPU - all other hardware and settings stayed exactly the same.

PC would boot perfectly fine, but it would consistently crash almost immediately after starting a game.

I confirmed that the problem went away when putting the 1070 back in and confirmed that there was no issues with the 3080 by putting it in another rig. Problem with the ITX PC would come back after re-installing the 3080.

I also tried running GPU benchmarks (such as furmark) to confirm if it was just some of the games I was playing or if just any graphics intensive thing would cause the PC to crash; running GPU benchmarks would also immediately crash the PC which means it did have something to do with the GPU.

After confirming that, here is a list of things I tried doing:

- uninstalled GPU drivers then reinstalled them directly from nvidia site; no good
- uninstalled/reinstalled GPU drivers but using EVGA drivers; no good.
  DDU; no good.
- tried running a separate PCI-e power cable to the 3080 as it was initially plugged in through pig-tails so it would have 2 separate PCI-e power cables directly to PSU; no good (recommend having separate PCI-e power cables regardless for high power draw GPUs)
- tried mobo CMOS reset as I did have some CPU undervolt settings; no good.
- tried installing evga precision to underclock and undervolt the card as it may have been crashing due to a power issue; no good.
- checked hardwareInfo to see if GPU core or memory temps, or power limits were causing crashing; nope. temps all good, core: 80c max, mem:85c max, not hitting power limit, pulling an expected amount of wattage when GPU load is running(200-300 something, can't remember exactly off the top of my head)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to my mobo's PCI-e slot settings in BIOS. I forget the exact location and the wording used for this, but it's the setting in the bios which sets the PCI-e gen (4 / 3 / etc.) By default, it's set to auto negotiate the gen speed as needed. I just manually set it to either PCI-e gen4 or gen3 (I forget exactly which one) but that was able to resolve the issue for me.

(May have also had to change the BIOS setting to set the PCI-e slot to x16 rather than auto negotiate speed/bifurcation - again sorry, this is all from memory)

I was even able to go back and undo some of the changes I made when troubleshooting this issue. I was able to redo my CPU undervolting, set XMP for ram, and set my GPU back to default.

No more crashing on my ITX build with my new rtx 3080!

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question, and providing useful insight to those who come after you. It is helpful :)